# Return user services details (OneDrive for Business, Outlook Online, Sharepoint Online, Calendar) using Grap Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Goal:
Return user services details like (OneDrive for Business, Outlook Online, Sharepoint Online, Calendar) from Office365 using Microsoft Graph Api.

I used this endpont:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/licenseDetails

But that return all service plan.

Do you know how to return the services available to a user using Grap Api?

Answer (score 0):

[License Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0) api contains information about **a license assigned to a user**, also with the servicePlans collection. If you don't want to see the service plans assigned with the license, you can use **$select** to filter it.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/licenseDetails?$select=id,skuId,skuPartNumber
```

[image]

**Update:**

One license will have many service plans. For example, I have a Office 365 E3 license, I will got the following service plans. You can find the reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference).

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know what are the skuId for OneDrive, Outlook and Sharepoint. Thanks.

Comment: @Oilid Sory for the delay. One license will have many service plans. You can find the skuId here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference